# Retrieving a JSON object within another one

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I have a simple JSON format text file and I am having some trouble retrieving values in the "pixel" array. 
Here is the file:

```
{ "luminaire" : 
  { "sensors": 
     { "pixel" : [2000,2001,2002] } 
  } 
}
```

The code I wrote in order to do this is the following:

```
//After parsing success...    
Json::Value pixel = root_["luminaire"].get("sensors" , "nothing").get("pixel" , "nopixel");
int value = pixel[0].asInt();
```

I tried many ways to do it but I keep getting the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Json::LogicError'
what():  in Json::Value::operator[](ArrayIndex): requires arrayValue
```

I also tried

```
Json::Value:ArrayIndex and root[0]
```

but I get the same error.
How can I retrieve the values in the "pixel" array?

Comment: Oh yes right it works now thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you mean `root_.get("luminaire")`?  After all, `luminaire` is a key name just like `sensors`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `root_.get("luminaire")`

```
root_.get("luminaire").get("sensors" , "nothing").get("pixel" , "nopixel");
```